# merge lists in runtime according to user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 4 lists like

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
list4 = []
```

then i need get user input and merge two lists at run time and print them ..

I have tried like this

```
first = input('enter 1st list')
second = input('enter 2nd list ')
if (first == 1):
    first  = list1
elif(first ==2):
    second = list2
....
....
```

but this is very long procedure and not appropriate for taking many inputs .

So please suggest me a  better method..

Comment: Can you explain this better? What do you mean by merge? Do you want them sorted? As tuples? Alternating?

Comment: Can you please tell us what you exactly trying to do. are the number of lists constant?. is there anyway to keep all the lists in a list?

Comment: Don't write `if (…):`, just write `if …:`. The parentheses are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `eval()` method in python3.x  if you are using python 2.x use `raw_input` .

Comment: This is *not* the most sound advice. There is no need to use `eval()` when better and more secure options exist.

Comment: Using `eval()` is not recommended especially when there is a better way, you can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/1982962)

Answer (score 2):

Put your 4 lists in *another* list:

```
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]
```

Now you can address them with indexing:

```
firstlist = lists[int(first) - 1]
```

Comment: i got it friends ..

    first = eval(input('enter 1st list'))
    second = eval(input('enter 2nd list '))

Any how thanks for support ....

Comment: I'd not use `eval()`; `int()` will do fine here.

Answer (score 0):

try this using dict

```
lists = {1: list1, 2: list2, 3:list3, 4:list4}

firstlist = lists[int(first)]
```